# Can't Hide Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

This should be straightforward, but I can't get it to work.  I want to hide tablix4, so I am modifying Tablix Properties --> Visibility --> Show or Hide based on formula:

=iif(IsNothing(First(Fields!ab_new_varietypermitname.Value)),True, False)

=iif(iif(Fields!ab_new_plantationstatus.Value="Test",Fields!ab_new_totalvinenumValue.Value,0) =0,True,false)

=iif(CountRows("Company") =0,true, false)
This shows the tablix, even if it's empty.

=iif(CountRows("Company") =0,false,true)
This hides the tablix, even if it has entries.

Can anyone recommend other things to try?
The tablix already has a filter on it of Fields!ab_new_plantationstatus.Value="Test"

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=IIF(RunningValue(IIF (Fields!ab_new_plantationstatus.Value ="Test",Fields!ab_new_totalvinenumValue.Value,0),SUM,"Company")=0,true,false)

This worked as a formula to hide the tablix.